# Merging multiple csv files in cmd

Tags: windows, csv, cmd, merge

I have multiple csv files of large size in a folder, say

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
combine.csv
```

And if I have to combine (append) all of them using cmd, I know that I have to use

```
copy *.csv targetfile.csv
```

My question is what if I have to combine the csv files which has the name **"file"** in it which are `file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv` in this case.

Comment: `copy file*.csv targetfile.csv`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I just figured out it is 
copy "file*".csv targetfile.csv

Comment: You're welcome! the quotes are not necessary here; if you want to use them, then it must read `copy "file*.csv" "target.csv". I recommend to add the `/B` switch like `copy /B ...` in order to avoid an _EOF_ character to be appended to the `target.csv` file...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@aschipfl already answered this in a comment, but I am answering this with some explanations:

```
copy file*.csv targetfile.csv
```

The above purely runs a single copy command for all file*.csv files and once off opens targetfile.csv and appends each file's content to it.

Additionally, if you have 100s of **different** filenames all together with `csv` extensions, you can also do this and ensure you exclude `targetfile.csv`

```
for %i in (*.csv) do if not "%i" == "MyTextOutput.csv" type %i >> targetfile.csv
```

The exact same line can be used in a batch file by simply adding an additional `%` to the meta variables.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.csv) do if /i not "%%i" == "targetfile.csv" type %%i >> targetfile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your expertise @Gerhard

Answer (score 2):

**For this In Mac/Linux You can use Cat command**

```
cat *.csv >targetData.csv
```

**And for Windows users have to do same with Type command**

```
type *.csv >targetData.csv
```